# Sort by Date, based on the selected date, then the nearest +/- date in MySQL Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

Selected Date = 9/6/2017 and Day Range = +/- 2. 
Output, Days should be ordered as follows:

```
1. 9/6/2017
2. 9/5/2017
3. 9/7/2017
4. 9/4/2017
5. 9/8/2017
```

Comment: Really the weirdest request.

Answer (score 0):

You should use expression in order clause, something like:

```
order by abs(Original_Date - Output_Date) asc
```

So this way you will get distance from original date (9/6/2017) to any other date, and don't forget to take absolute values (abs)

Answer (score 0):

I used Case statement in ORDER BY to achieve this.

```
 ORDER BY CASE when (DATE(created_on) =  DATE(in_selected_date)) THEN 1
     when (DATE(created_on) < DATE(in_selected_date) AND DATEDIFF(DATE(created_on), DATE(in_selected_date)) = -1)  THEN 2
    when (DATE(created_on) > DATE(in_selected_date) AND DATEDIFF(DATE(created_on), DATE(in_selected_date)) = 1)  THEN 3
     when (DATE(created_on) < DATE(in_selected_date) AND DATEDIFF(DATE(created_on), DATE(in_selected_date)) = -2)  THEN 4
    when (DATE(created_on) > DATE(in_selected_date) AND DATEDIFF(DATE(created_on), DATE(in_selected_date)) = 2)  THEN 5
    ELSE 1 END ASC
```